# disable busy indicator on href if onclick returns false

Tags: css, onclick, busyindicator

In my web pages I have a busy indicator like this:

```
window.onload = setupFunc;
function setupFunc() {
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].onclick = clickFunc;
  hideBusysign();
}

function hideBusysign() {
  document.body.style.cursor='default';
}

function showBusysign() {
  document.body.style.cursor='progress';
}

function clickFunc(eventData) {
  var clickedElement = (window.event) ? event.srcElement : eventData.target;
  if ((clickedElement.tagName.toUpperCase() == 'BUTTON' || clickedElement.tagName.toUpperCase() == 'A' ) || clickedElement.parentNode.tagName.toUpperCase() == 'A'
    || (clickedElement.tagName.toUpperCase() == 'INPUT' && (clickedElement.type.toUpperCase() == 'BUTTON' || clickedElement.type.toUpperCase() == 'SUBMIT')))
    && clickedElement.parentNode.id.toUpperCase() != 'NOBUSY'  ) {
    showBusysign();
  }
}
```

(To keep it simple I have removed the part for ajax requests)

The problem is: If there is a link <a href=... onclick=... and the onclick returns false, then the href is not "executed", but the busy indicator goes on (and does not go off anymore).

I have changed the

```
clickedElement.tagName.toUpperCase() == 'A'
```

to

```
(clickedElement.tagName.toUpperCase() == 'A' 
  && ! clickedElement.hasAttribute("onclick"))
```

but this is not a serious solution, as it presumes that links with onclick attribute will never go for the href.

Is there a possibility to know in a generic way, if the onclick will return true or false, e.g. if the href will be requested or not?

Comment: I don't understand - if an anchor tag has an href attribute and the href is an actual url, then the default behavior is for browser to go to that location. Why would it return false?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a stunning easy and well working solution by myself:

```
window.onbeforeunload = showBusysign;

function showBusysign() {
    document.body.style.cursor='progress';
}
```

:-)

In case it maybe helpfull for wicket programmers, this is my whole script:

```
window.onload = setupFunc;             // for ajax requests
window.onbeforeunload = showBusysign;  // for page requests

function setupFunc() {
    Wicket.Event.subscribe('/ajax/call/beforeSend', function( attributes, jqXHR, settings ) {
        showBusysign()
    });
    Wicket.Event.subscribe('/ajax/call/complete', function( attributes, jqXHR, textStatus) {
        hideBusysign()
    });
}

function hideBusysign() {
    document.body.style.cursor='default';
}

function showBusysign() {
    document.body.style.cursor='progress';
}
```